# Почему приложение вылетает?

Tags: java, android

Вот  код моей *MainActivity* и нажатие на любую кнопку приводит к вылету приложения (вылетает на эмуляторе и на реальном устройстве)

Вот что есть в Logcat

```
**2022-05-24 19:54:56.690 9768-9768/ru.n1ghtlightsapp.myapplication E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
2022-05-24 19:54:56.691 9768-9768/ru.n1ghtlightsapp.myapplication E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
2022-05-24 19:54:56.697 9768-9768/ru.n1ghtlightsapp.myapplication E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {ru.n1ghtlightsapp.myapplication/ru.n1ghtlightsapp.myapplication.NoteEditorActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1616)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4487)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:597)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4445)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:583)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4806)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4774)
        at ru.n1ghtlightsapp.myapplication.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:43)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3450)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:352)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:264)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1185)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:128)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1158)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3127)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4054)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3813)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.DropDownListView.onTouchEvent(DropDownListView.java:218)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView.onTouchEvent(MenuPopupWindow.java:138)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11776)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2962)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2643)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PopupWindow.java:2406)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12015)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4795)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4293)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4350)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6661)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6635)
        at android.view.ViewRootI
2022-05-24 19:54:56.697 9768-9768/ru.n1ghtlightsapp.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2022-05-24 19:54:56.702 9768-9768/ru.n1ghtlightsapp.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ru.n1ghtlightsapp.myapplication, PID: 9768
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {ru.n1ghtlightsapp.myapplication/ru.n1ghtlightsapp.myapplication.NoteEditorActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1616)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4487)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:597)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4445)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:583)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4806)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4774)
        at ru.n1ghtlightsapp.myapplication.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:43)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3450)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:352)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:264)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1185)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuPopup.onItemClick(MenuPopup.java:128)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1158)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3127)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4054)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3813)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.DropDownListView.onTouchEvent(DropDownListView.java:218)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView.onTouchEvent(MenuPopupWindow.java:138)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11776)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2962)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2643)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2968)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2657)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PopupWindow.java:2406)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12015)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4795)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4293)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4350)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
2022-05-24 19:54:56.703 9768-9768/ru.n1ghtlightsapp.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6661)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6596)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6764)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)**
```

Сам код:

```
package ru.n1ghtlightsapp.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.note_add, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.add_note) {

            // Going from MainActivity to NotesEditorActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteEditorActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.notes", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        HashSet<String> set = (HashSet<String>) sharedPreferences.getStringSet("notes", null);

        if (set == null) {

            notes.add("Example note");
        } else {
            notes = new ArrayList(set);
        }

        // Using custom listView Provided by Android Studio
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, notes);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                // Going from MainActivity to NotesEditorActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteEditorActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("noteId", i);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                final int itemToDelete = i;
                // To delete the data from the App
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setTitle("Are you sure?")
                        .setMessage("Do you want to delete this note?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                notes.remove(itemToDelete);
                                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.notes", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                HashSet<String> set = new HashSet(MainActivity.notes);
                                sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("notes", set).apply();
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}'
```

Comment: читай логи, там написано почему

Comment: Могу приложить скриншоты из Logcat если они помогут

Comment: гадать по коду это глупое занятие, так вам тут вряд ли помогут, есть вкладка logcat, там есть куча красного текста, его нужно в вопрос приложить

Comment: @Andrew добавил строчки из logcat

Comment: Вот и ответ: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {ru.n1ghtlightsapp.myapplication/ru.n1ghtlightsapp.myapplication.NoteEditorActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: У вас форма, которую вы запускаете, не прописана в манифесте

Comment: @ArtyMorris а как её тогда прописать, просто я еще немного не разбираюсь в Java

Comment: Открыть `AndroidManifest.xml` и вписать туда вашу активити. Скорее всего студия может сделать это за вас, если вы откроете класс этой активити, кликнете по его имени, потом по лампочке или `alt+enter` и по пункту `Add activity to manifest`